# Incrementing numbers when searching for a string in spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

I'm trying to create a report in google spreadsheet.

What I'm trying to do is

1. Look for a specific String (e.g. "state1") in one column
2. Each time that String is found in that column, I would like to Increment the number in a specific cell.

   `if('Sheet1'!K:K="state1"; add(b1, 1); add(b2, 0))`

Two problems:

1. With the 'sheet1'!K:K I do not seem to get to the sheet.
2. The if statement looks for just one match and increments, but does not work consecutively.

Comment: Is there a reason that you are not using COUNTIF?  You can use that to count the number of cells containing the target string.

`COUNTIF('Sheet1'!K:K,"state1")`

Comment: Well I guess the reason was me being a beginner at google spreadsheet.
Thank you very much, you solved the problem!

Comment: Yeah trying to set the thread to "answered" somehow... And upvote you...

Answer (score 1):

You can use that to count the number of cells containing the target string. `COUNTIF('Sheet1'!K:K,"state1")`